# Extracting numbers from the captured image in android

Tags: android

I am doing an android app which involves a concept where I have to extract numbers from the captured image. Can you please help me or guide me a link where I could find the appropriate tutorials?

Comment: Search: "android ocr"

Answer (score 0):

You have a good tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) where is explains method to create, to reading and writting files, in your case needs to read.

When you read this tutorial try my code that return a string of bytes:

```
public String formatPhoto_JPEGtoByteArray (String uri){
    // Read bitmap from file
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = null;

    try {
        stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(uri)));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

        byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteStream);

        // Convert ByteArrayOutputStream to byte array. Close stream.
        byte[] byteArray = byteStream.toByteArray();

        Log.e("-- FilesAndFolders.formatPhoto_JPEGtoByteArray --", "Last file of size: " + byteArray.length);

        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        byteStream.close();
        byteStream = null;

        return imageEncoded;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("-- FilesAndFolders.formatPhoto --", "Exception with " + uri,ex);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("-- FilesAndFolders.formatPhoto --", "Exception with " + uri,ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (stream != null) stream.close();
            if (byteStream != null) byteStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!